# i am Getting org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Unable to read XML while running simple hibernate project

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, log4j, nhibernate-mapping

I'm running my first hibernate project which saves user information such as id,name and address into mysql database

**This is my error log**

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.jboss.logging).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Unable to read XML
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.MappingReader.readMappingDocument(MappingReader.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.add(Configuration.java:490)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.add(Configuration.java:486)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.add(Configuration.java:659)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource(Configuration.java:742)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseMappingElement(Configuration.java:2197)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:2169)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2149)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2102)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2017)
    at mypack.DataInsertion.insertInfo(DataInsertion.java:18)
    at mypack.DataInsertion.main(DataInsertion.java:11)
Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: Error on line 3 of document  : The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed. Nested exception: The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:482)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.MappingReader.readMappingDocument(MappingReader.java:78)
    ... 11 more
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml (Configuration xml file)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
 "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
   <session-factory>

<!-- Related to the connection START -->   
   <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
   <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibdb</property>
   <property name="connection.user">root</property>
   <property name="connection.password">admin</property>
<!-- Related to the connection END -->     

<!-- Related to the hibernate properties START -->
   <property name="show_sql">true</property>
   <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
<!-- Related to the hibernate properties END -->     

<!-- List of XML mapping files -->
   <mapping resource="user.hbm.xml"/>

</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**user.hbm.xml (Mapping xml)**

```
<!-- Mapping File to POJO Class -->

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>

<class name="mypack.DataProvider" table="user_info">
<id name="user_id" column="table_id">
<generator class="assigned"/>
</id>

<property name="user_name" column = "name" />
<property name="user_address" column = "address" />

</class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

**DataProvider.java (POJO class)**

//POJO Class

```
package mypack;

public class DataProvider {

private int user_id;
private String user_name;
private String user_address;

public int getUser_id() {
    return user_id;
}
public void setUser_id(int user_id) {
    this.user_id = user_id;
}
public String getUser_name() {
    return user_name;
}
public void setUser_name(String user_name) {
    this.user_name = user_name;
}
public String getUser_address() {
    return user_address;
}
public void setUser_address(String user_address) {
    this.user_address = user_address;
}

}
```

**DataInsertion.java (Implentation java class)**

```
package mypack;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class DataInsertion {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DataInsertion().insertInfo();

    }

    public void insertInfo()
    {
        Configuration con = new Configuration();        //interation with hib
        con.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");            //registering to xml

        SessionFactory SF = con.buildSessionFactory(); //creating session
        Session session = SF.openSession();           //opening new session
        DataProvider provider = new DataProvider();
        provider.setUser_id(1);
        provider.setUser_name("Goutham");
        provider.setUser_address("Hunsur");

        Transaction TR = session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(provider);
        System.out.println("Object saved successfully");
        TR.commit();                                 //saving transaction
        session.close();
        SF.close();
    }

}
```

*Please advise me,,,
Thanks.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the comment line and blank line before the first tag in user.hbm.xml

Comment: log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.jboss.logging).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Object saved successfully
Hibernate: insert into user_info (name, address, table_id) values (?, ?, ?)
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement

Comment: Sorry i got the right output,,insert into user_info (name, address, table_id) ,here table_id should be just id.